# using for each while importing data from another file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a source file where users enter monthly data in each month's sheet (multiple sheets with Jan, Feb, ...).
In another file, I want users to enter year and month and my macro should import the relevant data from the source file. I tried to do the task with the following code but I received an unidentifiable error.

```
strAsset_Path = Asset_RS_URL & "\" & strYear & "\" & Asset_RS_FILENAME & strMonth

Set strAsset_CodeList = strAsset_Path & strMonth.Range("A3:A500").Value

For Each MyCell In strAsset_CodeList
    Response.Write MyCell Range("A3:A500").Value
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the other workbook via vba and read and copy the cell values from the sheet of your choice:

```
strAsset_Path = Asset_RS_URL & "\" & strYear & "\" & Asset_RS_FILENAME 

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strAsset_Path , ReadOnly:=True)

Set Rng = wb.Worksheets(strMonth).Range("A3:A500")

For Each mycell In Rng
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(mycell.Address).Value = wb.Worksheets(strMonth).Range(mycell.Address)
Next mycell

wb.Close
```